# How do I set a random Interval for ASP.NET AJAX Timer control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to set the Timer Interval to be 5000-10000 ms randomly using aspx only (without the C# code behind).

The following example raises the error message:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation '<%= Random.Next(5000,10000) %>' for the 'Interval' property.
```

**How do I correct the Interval variable to get a random interval calls?**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="<%= Random.Next(5000,10000) %>">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried to Convert.ToInt32, but it doesn't work.

Is it even possible?

For some inspiration, I managed to work this out with some C# code behind this way:

aspx :

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
```

C# :

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Timer1.Interval = random.Next(5000, 10000);
}
```

but again, I would like to get rid of the C# code.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= %>` tag will always return a string, as it's an equivalent to `Response.Write(" ")`.

Your alternative is code-behind (offering a good explanation of why you don't want to use code-behind might get some more interest from potential respondents). Or, use the `<%# %>` tag instead. Although, this will require the control be data-bound, which is probably an even less elegant solution than just using the code-behind.

Comment: The `<%# %>` never worked. I do use code behind, but the project goal is to get rid of most of the code behind without moving to Razor.

Comment: Indeed, `<%# %>` won't work unless you're data bound, and as I say, that's not a particularly _elegant_ solution. I think you might be at an impasse. I'd certainly be curious to see if anyone else has any answers, as it's something I've tried to find myself in the past without success.